# Header annotation with "." in header name, such as @Header("foo.bar"), doesn't map

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-dsl

I have a simple Spring Integration message endpoint with the signature:

```
@Transformer
String handleMessage(@Payload String payload, @Header("nerf") String nerf, @Header("foo.bar") String foobar) {
 //...
}
```

The variable `nerf` always contains the header value it received from Kafka. The variable `foobar` is always null, despite the header named `foo.bar` existing in the inbound message.

This is a simple DSL-based flow coming straight off the Kafka binder.

It seems that any parameter with a name that contains the `.` character doesn't get mapped properly.

What am I doing wrong? Is the @Header(name) a SpEL expression?

Comment: Can you try "'foo.bar'"? Basically, i suspect dot is interpreted by property accessor as path to inner property. Basically wrap foo.bar in single quotes

Comment: Unfortunately, quoting doesn't help; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's designed that way; so you can extract property `bar` from a header named `foo`.

However, quoting it as Oleg suggested should work, but does not; we end up looking for header `''foo'` with property `bar'`.

I have opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3083).

Comment: Looks like the fix is in: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3084